# Version rollback attack prevention in TLS 1.2?

Tags: protocol-design, tls, man-in-the-middle

Are there any methods to prevent version rollback attack while using TLS 1.2 (apart from disabling lower versions)? I've read about how TLS 1.3 provides a downgrade protection mechanism which is embedded in the server’s random nonce. Is there any such mechanism in TLS 1.2?

Comment: As far as I know, no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Rollback** by tampering the ClientHello/ServerHello exchange is detected and blocked by Finished in all versions of TLS. For plain-RSA keyexchange the client version is additionally 'smuggled' in the [encrypted premaster secret](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5246#section-7.4.7.1) which allows earlier detection -- but since the early 2010s (teens?) plain-RSA has mostly been deprecated or dropped because it doesn't provide Forward Secrecy. For (all) suites using client authentication in TLS 1.0-1.2 the client signature also covers the transcript including the version, thus detecting rollback, but using client authentication is optional and rare.

**Downgrade** by causing a higher version handshake to fail so that a client is induced to use (and accept) a lower version varies.

TLS 1.0-1.2 specify a check against downgrade *to SSLv2* by setting the low bytes of the premaster secret before encryption in plain-RSA keyexchange (which is the only keyexchange in SSLv2); this is E.2 in RFC 2246 and 4346 and [E.3 in RFC 5246](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5246#appendix-E.3). But by the mid-to-late noughties, when 1.1 and 1.2 were adopted, pracically everybody/everything had dropped SSLv2, and it was officially prohibited by RFC6176 in 2011, so this became moot. (Java JSSE until j7 in 2011 used by default the 'transitional' *hello format* from SSLv2, but JSSE never supported actual SSLv2 protocol.)

For TLS 1.0-1.2 [RFC 7507](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7507) in 2015 defines a SCSV to detect downgrade (and is referenced in RFC8446, which incorporates the alert code).